# What is the talmudic or midrashic term for "do not take the text literally?"

Tags: talmud-gemara, midrash

I need a word that says the opposite of the term, כמשמעו.

Comment: I have only ever seen לא כמשמעו.

Comment: How about לאו דוקא, which is ubiquitous in divrei Chazal.

Comment: user2275 welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please consider registering your account to afford yourself a better site experience, and consider choosing a new username unless you have some special attachment to the number 2275! I look forward to seeing you around.

Answer (score 5):

אמר רבא אע"ג דבכל התורה כולה אין מקרא יוצא מידי פשוטו הכא אתאי גזרה שוה **אפיקתיה מפשטיה לגמרי**. יבמות כד ע''ב
"Says Rava: even though in all of the Torah the verse does not leave its most simple reading, here, however, the Gezeira Shava comes and **removes it from its simple meaning completely."** Yevamot 24a.

Comment: It might be better if you translated the entire passage and highlighted the phrase itself. +1 for coming up with it (especially so quickly), though.

Answer (score 1):

Would this phrase work

פשוטו כמדרשו

as used here

http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=1&mefaresh=ramban&perek=9

scroll down to pasuk 7

Answer (score 0):

I think כלומר fits the bill nicely.